# How to see souce code of Compiled C code in R

Tags: c, r, compiled

I would like to how to view source code of compiled C code in R.

I am looking for C code for package "nlm"; the corresponding compiled C code is "C_nlm".

I am new to R, so please suggest your inputs in a basic way.

Thanks

Comment: Download the package source, and read it

Comment: Sounds to me like you're actually in need of a decompiler, like boomerang. C isn't a scripting language, after all...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem R packages are open-source. No decompiler required to view the source code.

Comment: @Roland: in which case, David Heffernan's comment is the answer... :-P

Comment: Actually I think you're looking for https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c and/or https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/uncmin.c. `nlm` is not a "package", it's a **function** that is part of base R.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here in this [R News article about sources](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf)

Also some googling around, I found references that the functionality you are looking for is in:

```
src/main/optimize.c
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me where can I get the source code for - optimize.c ?

Comment: in the source code of R ... What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I got the source code... :)