# How does one see the C code behind a function in igraph package?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to study the detailed code behind certain functions in `igraph` package in R.

For example in the code chunk below I wanted to see the function behind fast greedy clustering. `igraph::cluster_fast_greedy` shows the R function. It, in turn, calls on certain functions written in C, most importantly `C_R_igraph_community_fastgreedy`. It is clear that the following code does not do the clustering directly but calls the aforementioned C function. I want to know how to view and edit those.

I know that using `trace()` would allow me to edit the R function.

```
> igraph::cluster_fast_greedy
function (graph, merges = TRUE, modularity = TRUE, membership = TRUE, 
    weights = E(graph)$weight) 
{
    if (!is_igraph(graph)) {
        stop("Not a graph object")
    }
    if (!is.null(weights)) {
        weights <- as.numeric(weights)
    }
    on.exit(.Call(C_R_igraph_finalizer))
    res <- .Call(C_R_igraph_community_fastgreedy, graph, as.logical(merges), 
        as.logical(modularity), as.logical(membership), weights)
    if (igraph_opt("add.vertex.names") && is_named(graph)) {
        res$names <- V(graph)$name
    }
    res$algorithm <- "fast greedy"
    res$vcount <- vcount(graph)
    res$membership <- res$membership + 1
    res$merges <- res$merges + 1
    class(res) <- "communities"
    res
}
<bytecode: 0x000001d95fb78be0>
<environment: namespace:igraph>
```

I am posting this question at the risk of being marked duplicate, but the answers to previous similar questions have not been of much help to me. They can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065474/how-to-see-souce-code-of-compiled-c-code-in-r).

I have checked the folder where `igraph` is downloaded in my computer and did not find any such file that seemed relatable.

I have also looked at their [github](https://github.com/cran/igraph/tree/ba26ee42b133ab383aba8acb3c23daf74324fd63/R).

Comment: The C code is in the `src` folder, and the function your'e after is [here](https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/ba26ee42b133ab383aba8acb3c23daf74324fd63/src/fast_community.c#L601). If you want to edit the code, you'll need to fork the github project, edit it and re-build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` code for `R` packages are found inside the `src/` folder:
[src folder of igraph](https://github.com/cran/igraph/tree/ba26ee42b133ab383aba8acb3c23daf74324fd63/src).

In your case, the function is [here](https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/ba26ee42b133ab383aba8acb3c23daf74324fd63/src/fast_community.c#L601).

Comment: I see, so it is always the `src` folder. Thank you!

Comment: @Anirban_Mitra No, it is not. This answer is inaccurate, and refers only to the package submitted to CRAN.

Answer (score 2):

[igraph](https://igraph.org/) is a C library, with high-level interfaces in multiple languages, including R, Python and Mathematica. There are corresponding repositories [on GitHub](https://github.com/igraph/).

The source code of igraph's C core is at https://github.com/igraph/igraph. Almost all algorithms that you can access through R/igraph are implemented here.

The code for the R interface is at https://github.com/igraph/rigraph. The latest version of the R interface will not typically use the latest *released* version of the C core. To find out which version of the C core is used, look in the `cigraph` subdirectory, which is a git submodule pointing to a specific commit of the C core.

Note that most of the glue code between the C core and the R interface is automatically generated from the [`functions.def` file](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/interfaces/functions.def), so you will not find it in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and also clarifying in the other answer.